# 16.04: programs like Nautilus or gnome-screenshot hang for 20 seconds before opening

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, nautilus, gnome-screenshot

**Summary**: sometimes launching Nautilus or taking a screenshot takes 20 seconds or more. The only solution seems to be rebooting. At every reboot I have 50% chance of this occurring again.

---

**See updates at the bottom!**

---

I have a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 (pre)installed. Some times (I'd say, every 2 sessions) I have my entire session affected by a problem with **some applications hanging or not starting at all**. This is usually solved by rebooting (which isn't ideal).

The most common way I realise that the current session is affected, is by **trying to open a nautilus window** (by clicking on the "Files" dock icon).  **The window will open, but only after ~20 seconds**.

Also **if I try to launch a File dialog from within other programs** (e.g. when doing *File > Open* or *Mail > Attach*), **the file picker will appear after 20 seconds, freezing the parent program** in the meantime.

Another thing that happens is that if I launch `gnome-screenshot` from the dock (equivalent to `gnome-screenshot -i`), it doesn't hang but **after I click *Take Screenshot* it takes ~20 seconds** before actually taking the screenshot. In the meantime, I can't seem to launch other instances of `gnome-screenshot`.

The majority of other programs I use are unaffected by this.

Additional info:

- I have a NVIDIA gpu, but this happens regardless of it being active or disabled through `nvidia-prime`
- The problem doesn't happen at every boot, but once I notice it, it is reproduced 100% of the time within that session
- The laptop hasn't been suspended when this problem appears. The problem, when it appears, seems to appear since booting.
- I always make all the updates. This has always happened since I started using this laptop (8 months)

---

**Updates 19 Aug** (thanks Robert Riedl for making me look at peripherals and syslogs):

---

Looking at the `/var/log/syslog`s, I can notice these different behaviors:

- `gnome-screenshot`: good session:

```
    Aug 19 08:13:01 quokka dbus[964]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
    Aug 19 08:13:01 quokka systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
    Aug 19 08:13:01 quokka kernel: [  162.129006] talpa-vfshook: devpts is on the skip list, not patching
    Aug 19 08:13:01 quokka kernel: [  162.129031] talpa-vfshook: mqueue is on the skip list, not patching
    Aug 19 08:13:01 quokka kernel: [  162.129037] talpa-vfshook: Patching hugetlbfs
    Aug 19 08:13:01 quokka dbus[964]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
    Aug 19 08:13:01 quokka systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
```

- `gnome-screenshot`: bad session:

  Nothing on fire; then when eventually the screenshot is taken, only this line

```
      Aug 19 07:57:51 quokka dbus[1029]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
```

- `nautilus`: good session:

  No relevant syslogs
- `nautilus`: bad session:

  Nothing on fire; then when eventually the window is open, only this line

```
      Aug 19 08:01:31 quokka dbus[1029]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
```

Comment: How much RAM does the computer have?

Comment: @DanielMassey 16GB (+ swap)

Comment: I think in situations like these, formatting the drives which have an operating system and doing a clean install is less effort than trying to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @xubuntu not everybody can, at any moment, format and clean install. If there is a bug that affects multiple people on a maintained version of the OS, it's desirable to have a solution available on askubuntu for them to find in a hurry.

Comment: Once this happens, have you checked the log files `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages`? This could be some I/O or interrupt issue. Do you have any peripherals ?

Comment: If you close all Nautilus windows (`killall nautilus`) and log system calls with strace (`strace -o mylog.txt nautilus`), this can often help diagnose what's going on. The output will be very long, so you may want to use a pastebin.

Comment: Use `strace -o mylog2.txt -rTC nautilus` to get time spent in the syscalls.

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver when I launch `nautilus`, the CLI call just works in 5 milliseconds and gives me back my prompt (and `strace -rTC` stops updating after the first 5ms, showing no particular strange behaviour). But the window is not created until 20 seconds after (with no extra output)

Comment: @RobertRiedl I've updated the question with results from your suggestion

Comment: Hello, @NicolaSap, what option is checked in your system for **Show the menu bar for a window** (within Settings > Appearance > Behavior)?

Comment: @pa4080 "in the menu bar"

Comment: @NicolaSap Interesting, I do not get the prompt back on my machine. Make sure there are no existing Nautilus processes running (`pgrep nautilus`) and try adding the `-f` flag to trace child processes (e.g. `strace -o mylog.txt -frTC nautilus`). Then watch the output in a new terminal (`tail -f mylog.txt`).

Answer (score 1):

### Update August 19, 2019

---

Sounds like this [2 year old bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224787):

> the solution seems to be adding
>
> ```
> dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
> ```
>
> to `.xinitrc` or `.xsession`.

---

### Original Answer

This thread has techniques you can use to narrow down the problem:

- [Nautilus 3.30 starts very slowly, and I see error messages running Nautilus from the terminal](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/tracker/issues/43)

The next time it happens, rather than starting Nautilus from the GUI desktop or menu open a terminal and type `nautilus`. Then you will hopefully see some error messages that tell you the exact problem.

In the link above the solution hinted at was to use:

```
cp /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ~/.xinitrc
```

Then edit the file `~/.xinitrc` and add the `dbus` command. On my system the end result would look like this:

```
$ cat ~/.xinitrc

#!/bin/sh

# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)

# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I get the exact same five `GLib-GIO`, `GLib-GObject` and `Gtk` messages on both a good session and a bad session. Also, my behavior differs from the one in the thread as in mine not only the first launch is affected.

Comment: Note: I launch `nautilus`, the warnings appear immediately and I get my terminal back immediately, but the windows appears 20 seconds later without any new printout (but with `Aug 19 08:01:31 quokka dbus[1029]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'` in the syslogs)

Comment: @NicolaSap The error messages helped me update the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: That's seems like a very promising direction! However I don't understand exactly how to implement it. If a session is corrupted, running that `dbus-update-activation-environment` line (with or without sudo) won't fix the session. As for adding it to a init file, I don't have either `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`. I've tried creating the former with the suggested line, and it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Can you remove the bit about `nautilus` please ? Since this is clearly not the solution. And please link to the bug report instead of or at least in addition to the forum link. I know the archlinux userbase keeps their content very consistent, but still..

Comment: I'll update the answer after work. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @NicolaSap Sorry for delay. I've added `~/.xinitrc` file create to answer.

Comment: @RobertRiedl Thanks for your input. I've made the suggested changes.

Comment: I haven't tested the latest changes yet and I won't have time before the bounty expires. I am awarding the bounty but I'll be back again with feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nicola,

In addition to looking at the logs recommend I highly recommend opening a terminal and watching a running "top" session before duplicating the problem.

Also you can run it from the F1 or other txt login sessions, or even remotely through ssh if the session hangs.

I have had various issues with nautilus and apps (mostly via vnc but sometimes at host), and this has sometimes lead to a resolution.

For instance you might be able to tell which process is taking up all the time, the app, nautilus or other.

Curt